# Make a GUI executing a python script

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

There is a script that I am making with python which I should type in the command like :

```
python qwer.py -q hello -w thingies -e /root/text.txt -r 6
```

-q and -w are strings, -e is for the directory, -r is for a number.
I would like to make a GUI for this, but inside this script.
So is there a way to do it in tkinter, and in like this format? :

```
from Tkinter import *
def GUI:
    #The GUI Script for Tkinter.
    #get the string value for -q and -w.
    #get the directory path for -e.
    #get the number for -r.

def main:
    #get the values from the def GUI
    #script (do things)
```

and combine those two in one script.
I would like the input to be a bar(?) to type the values in.
How do I do it?

Comment: You can run any program using `subprocess` module. Or if script has functions then you could try do `import qwer` and execute `qwer.some_function()`.

Comment: This is very vague, can you provide an example on the main?

Comment: `tkinter` has `Entry` widget to input value - [documentation on effbot.org](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-index.htm)

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do it, but your question is too broad for this site. Your first step should be to work through a tkinter tutorial.

Comment: You may be very interested in [Gooey](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Gooey).